# JQuery/Sortable - Drag and Drop Target List's Id

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drag-and-drop, droppable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list with jQuery `sortable` on asp.net. I want to get the `id` of the target list.

When I drag and drop an item to the target `UL` it is giving me an `id` which I get it from.

JavaScript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function textUl() {
        $('ul').bind('mouseup',function() {
            $('#REL_UL').val($(this).attr('id'));
        }  
    }
</script>
```

How to obtain target UL's `id`.

Answer (score 0):

By using `mouseenter` on my page's `ul`s, I am able to pass along their `id`'s to my `REL_UL` element.

```
$('ul').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#REL_UL').val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```